# create segue with uid as property

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a segue which leads the current user to chat vc by the given userID of the post creator:

My segue now:

```
    var user: User?
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
    }
```

The ChatLogController.user:

```
var user: User?   {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = user?.name
        observeMessages()
    }
}
```

and the userClass:

```
class User: NSObject {
var id: String?
var name: String?
var email: String?
var profileImageUrl: String?
init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
}
```

}

What I now want to have is that the segue goes directly to a chatLogController of a specific user 
I know that I need to connect the uid of the user I want to connect with, I also got this property saved under

```
var jobCreatorID: String?
```

But in how far do I need to change my code to get it working?

Comment: why are you settign a optional user

Answer (score 0):

you should change this

```
var user: User?
```

since you are setting this user to nextviewController in this

```
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
```

but this user is the one avobe declare as user? so not user instance.  if this class have a user object then your should assing that user

```
chatLogController.user = self.user
```

and in your ChatLogController `viewDidLoad`set the title and get the user id like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = self.user
}
```

so from this user you got the id.